# Cannot get ytRating from YouTube Data API v3 with PHP

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Using PHP I can get some information from the API but I can't work out to get the full API.

Here's what I have at the moment:

```
// url with $vID being my video ID and $API_key being the access key
$api_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=status&id=' . $vID . '&key=' . $API_key;

// get contents
$videoInfo = file_get_contents( $api_url );
```

This will get me the first block of the API, something like this:

```
VidInfo: { "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse", 
            "etag": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
            "items": [ 
                { "kind": "youtube#video", 
                "etag": "yyyyyyyyyyy", 
                "id": "zzzzzz", 
                "status": { 
                    "uploadStatus": "processed", 
                    "privacyStatus": "public", 
                    "license": "youtube", 
                    "embeddable": true, 
                    "publicStatsViewable": true, 
                    "madeForKids": false 
                    } 
                } 
            ], 
            "pageInfo": { "totalResults": 1, "resultsPerPage": 1 } 
        }
```

However, the full API response should look like this:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"mPrpS7Nrk6Ggi_P7VJ8-KsEOiIw/el3Y0P65UwM366CJD3POX-W4y0c\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"mPrpS7Nrk6Ggi_P7VJ8-KsEOiIw/Rn64PVwC0Uhr4xp41vDOqygjJ9c\"",
   "id": "VIDEO_ID",
   "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT10M6S",
    "dimension": "2d",
    "definition": "hd",
    "caption": "false",
    "licensedContent": false,
    "contentRating": {
     "ytRating": "ytAgeRestricted"
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

What I'm particularly interested in is the **ytRating** to see if the video is restricted, but I can't find a way to find that in the response I'm getting.

Can anyone help me out here please?

Comment: You are only asking for the `status` part, apparently you want to ask for `contentDetails` as well. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#parameters

Comment: Why not use the PHP client library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CBroe [said above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66224667/cannot-get-rating-for-youtube-v3-api-with-php#comment117082779_66224667), your call to the [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) API endpoint is missing a required `contentDetails` [`part`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#part) for to be able to obtain the value of the property of your interest [`contentDetails.contentRating.ytRating`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.contentRating.ytRating).

Have your URL changed to:

`$api_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=status,contentDetails&id=' . $vID . '&key=' . $API_key`.

Do note also that it's good practice to employ the [`fields`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#fields) request parameter, for to ask from the API only the info that's of actual use. If interested only in `ytRating`, then have your URL as shown:

`$api_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&fields=items/contentDetails/contentRating/ytRating&id=' . $vID . '&key=' . $API_key`.

Comment: Thanks - that's got it now :)